# Recorded Audio not recognized by Google Speech API

Tags: pi-2, speech-recognition

I've looked at several tutorials/examples of setting up Speech to Text from command line but I can't figure out what my problem is. This is the example I have followed most closely: [Raspberry Pi voice recognition works like Siri](http://blog.oscarliang.net/raspberry-pi-voice-recognition-works-like-siri/), but still can't get things to work.

1. I set up my Logitech c270 and `arecord` appears to be working correctly.

   ```
   arecord -D "plughw:1,0" -f cd -d 5 -r 16000 -t wav | flac - -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -o file.flac
   ```
2. Instead of using `ffmpeg` I decided to go with `flac` to convert my .wav file to .flac, and when I run `mplayer file.flac` the file sounds good.
3. When submitting my .flac file using `wget` I see from my Google Developers Console that it records a successful request, but returns the following json:

   ```
   {"result":[]}
   ```

Do I have my settings set up properly, or does Google speech API require a specific bit rate?

To further test I downloaded a free .wav file from the following page:

http://www.wavsource.com/snds_2016-01-10_6357263721580594/people/men/about_time.wav (U8 format with 11025 Rate)

...then converted this to flac:

```
flac about_time.wav -f --best --sample-rate 16000 -o file.flac
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0" --post-file file.flac --header "Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000" -O - "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?lang=en-us?key=my-key" >stt.txt
echo -n "You Said: "
cat stt.txt
```

and got the following json file:

```
{"result":[]}
{"result":[{"alternative":[{"transcript":"it's about time you got here","confidence":0.96557111},
{"transcript":"it's about time you got it"},
{"transcript":"it's about time you got"},
{"transcript":"it's about time you guys"},
{"transcript":"it's about time you got you"}],
"final":true}],"result_index":0}
```

Any ideas where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I tweaked my settings and for some reason the Google Speech API likes the Unsigned 8bit 11025Hz recording so I changed my code to be the following and now it works:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Recording..."
arecord -D "plughw:1,0" -f U8 -r 11025 -d 5 | flac - -f --best --sample-rate 11025 -o file.flac

echo "Processing..."
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0" --post-file file.flac --header "Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=11025" -O - "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?lang=en-us?key=my-key" > stt.txt

echo -n "You Said: "
cat stt.txt
```

Comment: I hab the same problem and change the sampling rate didnt worked for me.
U have tip?

Comment: I got it working, but it still was returning nothing in the JSON file.  I double checked to make sure everything was working correctly, and it turned out that the cheap mic ($10) that I bought was recording, but it was very quiet.  I have since bought a new web cam as suggested in some of the tutorials for about $30 and it recorded loud enough for the Google Speech API to translate it.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and solved it by adding -c 1 to arecord, so it uses only one channel. found a hint on another page